# Convert to HTML the output of Powershell

Tags: backup, powershell

I have been working on a Powershell Script that generates email of the Windows backup event. The problem is the formatting looks bad.

> ```
> Subject: Computer name status [backup was successful]
>
> Tuesday, December 29, 2015 2:55 AM
> Index              : 19160
> EntryType          : Warning
> InstanceId         : 4099
> Message            : Backup was cancelled.
> Category           : (0)
> CategoryNumber     : 0
> ReplacementStrings : {}
> Source             : Windows Backup
> TimeGenerated      : 29-Dec-15 12:42:35 PM
> TimeWritten        : 29-Dec-15 12:42:35 PM
> UserName           :
> ```

I would like to have a colorful HTML report.

Here is the script

```
$Event = Get-eventlog -log application -Newest 1 -source "Windows Backup"
$Status= $Event.Message 
$From = "email@email.com"
$To = "email@email.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp"
$SMTPPort = "port"
$Username = "email"
$Password = "***"
$Subject = "$computer, $status"
$Body =  $event | format-list  | out-string
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $false
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body); 
$computer = "$env:computername"
```

Comment: Could you add your actual issue to the question? From the title, I think I infer what you are asking, but I'm not certain.

Comment: If you see the script the email body is just plain text of eventlog, i need help converting to HTML format so it looks good

Answer (score 4):

The key change that you'll want to make is during the object-to-string conversion. Right now, you're using `format-list` where you will want to use a different converter, for example, the `FormatTo-HTML` cmdlet. Here is a [technet article about FormatTo-HTML](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156817.aspx) and some documentation on [FormatTo-HTML from ss64.com](http://ss64.com/ps/convertto-html.html)

You can reference a css file with `-cssuri`, but this is only included as a link, so it won't be particularly useful to use a local file. Instead, you could include a html `<style/>` element in a string passed to the `-head` flag.

FormatTo-HTML has its limitations, like not producing alternating row styles for coloration, but it may be suitable for your needs.

Additionally, you need to set the `IsBodyHTML` property on the message. To do so, you need to create a MailMessage object instead of using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient::Send` to create one for you. For example:

```
$mailMsg = new-object  System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $From $To
$mailMsg.Subject = "$computer, $status"
$mailMsg.IsBodyHTML = $true
$mailMsg.Body = $event | FormatTo-HTML -title "System Status for $computer" | out-string
$smtp.Send($mailMsg)
```

Comment: hey guys i got this superb script https://gist.github.com/andreagx/8507883